# How to get the maximum value between the column `start` is true and the column `end` is true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Get the qualified value of `A` and assign it to the column `expect`

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['A']=[100, 90, 76, 45, 89, 15, 52, 80, 95, 74]
df['start']=[False,True,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False]
df['end']=[False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False,True,False]
```

The expected table:

```
   A    start   end expected
100 FALSE   FALSE   
90  TRUE    FALSE   
76  FALSE   FALSE   
45  FALSE   FALSE   
89  FALSE   TRUE    90
15  FALSE   FALSE   90
52  TRUE    FALSE   90
80  FALSE   FALSE   90
95  FALSE   TRUE    80
74  FALSE   FALSE   80
```

I thought of a way, is there a more suitable way?

```
g=df.groupby((df['start']|df['end']).cumsum())
df['expected']=g['A'].cummax().shift().where(df['end']).ffill()
```

Comment: What if the first `True` of `end` comes before `start`?

Comment: np.nan instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# identify values between start and end
m = (df['start'].where(df['start'])
     .fillna((~df['end']).where(df['end']))
     .ffill().fillna(False)
     )

# get max per start group
mx = df.loc[m, 'A'].groupby(df['start'].cumsum()).max()

# map on end group 
df['expected'] = df['end'].cumsum().map(mx)
```

Output:

```
     A  start    end  expected
0  100  False  False       NaN
1   90   True  False       NaN
2   76  False  False       NaN
3   45  False  False       NaN
4   89  False   True      90.0
5   15  False  False      90.0
6   52   True  False      90.0
7   80  False  False      90.0
8   95  False   True      80.0
9   74  False  False      80.0
```

Intermediates:

```
     A  start    end  expected      m  start_group  end_group
0  100  False  False       NaN  False            0          0
1   90   True  False       NaN   True            1          0
2   76  False  False       NaN   True            1          0
3   45  False  False       NaN   True            1          0
4   89  False   True      90.0  False            1          1
5   15  False  False      90.0  False            1          1
6   52   True  False      90.0   True            2          1
7   80  False  False      90.0   True            2          1
8   95  False   True      80.0  False            2          2
9   74  False  False      80.0  False            2          2

# mx
start
1    90
2    80
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
s = (df.loc[df[['start','end']].sum(axis=1).cumsum().mod(2).astype(bool)]
.groupby(df['start'].cumsum())['A'].max())

df['end'].cumsum().map(s).where(df['end'].cummax())
```

or

```
m = df['start'].where(df['start'] | df['end']).ffill().fillna(False)

df['end'].cumsum().map(df.loc[m].groupby(df['start'].cumsum())['A'].max())
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4    90.0
5    90.0
6    90.0
7    90.0
8    80.0
9    80.0
```